# What is the meaning of mode(x).mode[0]?

Tags: statistics, mode

I am trying to find mode along a column(named Outlet_Size) of a dataset using pandas library of python which contains values in the form of {small, medium,large} corresponding to 10 different outlet stores with total of 1000+ rows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjSnd.png).
For Finding the mode along that column for each store type the following code was used:

## Determing the mode for each type of outlet(10 different types)

**outlet_size_mode = data.pivot_table(values='Outlet_Size', columns='Outlet_Type',aggfunc=(lambda x:mode(x).mode[0]) )** .

However I am unable to understand the format of using the lambda function mode(x).mode[0]. What is the meaning of that?

Comment: Could you give more context. It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Hello @Atsch.. I have edited the question. Hope I made it informative this time for you to understand. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share more details? it is not clear what library you are using, what type data is or where mode is defined.

Comment: Actually just now I came across my answer for what I was searching. Basically for me mode(x) was fine but additionally .mode[0] was confusing me. So I came to know that for a column having several rows mode(x) can be an array as there can be multiple values with high frequency. We will take the first one by default always using: mode[0] at the end.  Btw Thanks @Atsch.

Comment: Write this up as an answer for some "free" reputation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a column having several rows mode(x) can be an array as there can be multiple values with high frequency. We will take the first one by default always using: mode[0] at the end.